# Third party library dependency versioning strategy

Tags: ios, cocoapods, dependency-management

We are using Cocoapods as dependency manager for our project, and I realized we don't really have a strategy when it comes to versioning.

Our podfile contains all sorts of syntax such as optimistic operator, logical operator, exact versioning ... etc

```
pod 'RxSwift'
pod 'RxCocoa', '~> 3.0'
pod 'RxAlamofire', '>= 3.0.3'
pod 'RxGesture', '1.0.1'
```

I am very well aware of what each and every operator does, but I don't know when to choose one over another, what are the possible use cases, and best practices for these operators.

Is it considered as a best practice to always use latest version if you can (such as `pod 'RxSwift'`) or is it better to lock to specific version number, or use optimistic operator (`~>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a borderline appropriate question for stackoverflow since there could be a lot of opinions. Here's an attempt at an objective concrete answer.

Start with a good understanding of [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/).

Then your tolerance for accepting patch, minor, and major version dependencies depends upon the stability versus desire for new features that you want for each of those dependencies intersected with the testing capability.

For example:

- If you don't trust the dependency to follow semantic versioning and/or the existing version meets all needs, lock it to a particular exact version.
- If you want bug fixes, but don't care about new features, use the `~` operator to accept patch updates.
- If you want new features, but don't want the existing build to break, allow minor updates.
- If you always want the latest and are willing to deal with breaking changes, don't specify a version constraint at all.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm leaving this Google Developers video, which is quite similar to your answer for future visitors https://youtu.be/x4ARXyovvPc